# WIll "helm upgrade" restart PODS even if they are not affected by upgrade?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My helm chart has some 12 PODS. When I did `helm upgrade` after changing some values all the PODs are restarted except for one.

**My question is**:

Will `helm upgrade` restart the PODS even if they are not affected by upgrade?

**Putting it in another way**:

Is it `helm upgrade` restart PODs only if they are affected by upgrade?

Comment: wasn't there any pre-existing release on which you executed helm upgrade ? just helm upgrade should not get executed

Comment: you are talking about helm itself or another service you have installed through helm?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I am concerned helm restart only the pods which are affected by upgrade

If You want to restart ALL pods you can use --recreate-pods flag

> --recreate-pods      ->      performs pods restart for the resource if applicable

For example if You have dashboard chart, You can use this command to restart every pod.

```
helm upgrade --recreate-pods -i k8s-dashboard stable/k8s-dashboard
```

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5218) which provide another workaround for it

> Every time you need to restart the pods, change the value of that annotation. A good annotation could be timestamp
>
> First, add an annotation to the pod. If your chart is of kind Deployment, add annotation to spec.template.metadata.annotations. For example:

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ecf-helm-satellite-qa
      annotations:
        timestamp: "{{ .Values.timestamp }}"
```

> Deploy that. Now, every time you set timestamp in helm command. Kubernetes will rollout a new update without downtime.

```
helm upgrade ecf-helm-satellite-qa . --set-string timestamp=a_random_value
```

Comment: `--recreate-pods` was removed with Helm 3. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 52):

The flag **`--recreate-pods`** was marked as **deprecated** in Helm 2 and was **removed** with Helm 3.

Helm suggests to either add **checksums** of other files which could have changed like this

```
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

or to add an annotation with a **random number** which forces an update on each rollout:

```
      annotations:
        rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}
```

See Helm docs: https://v3.helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: When i add `rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}` in all my deployments, `helm upgrade` restarts all deployments

Comment: So, if I understand if a chart don't do that and you just use the chart you need to manually use kubectl to restart or kill all the pods ?

Comment: Using `randAlphaNum 5` there's a 20% chance that the same number gets generated and therefore pods don't restart.

Comment: @Alex I think you are wrong. `randAlphaNum 5` generates a string with length 5 with chars [0-9a-ZA-Z]. So the probability is roughly 1:10^9 ( (10+26+26)^5 )

Comment: @Datz, you're totally right. [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#randalphanum-randalpha-randnumeric-and-randascii) for reference.

Answer (score 16):

`--recreate-pods` has been removed in helm 3 and that certainly got the attention of [some helm users](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8271).

I force the pods to be recreated using a timestamp in the deployment pod spec. Note that it has to be in the spec, this will not work at the deployment top level:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        releaseTime: {{ dateInZone "2006-01-02 15:04:05Z" (now) "UTC"| quote }}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need delete the job first,
and run

```
helm history <release_name>
helm rollback <release_name> <number> --recreate-pods
```

Answer (score 2):

I have defined a template helper using the recommendations, also adding it here so that I won't forget :)

```
{{- define "vtd2-consumer.annotations" -}}
{{ .Values.podAnnotations | toYaml }}
releaseTime: {{ dateInZone "2006-01-02 15:04:05Z" (now) "UTC"| quote }}
rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 5 | quote }}
checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/config.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
{{- end }}
```

Remove decide which method you like releaseTime, rollme or checksum/config, pretty sure you don't need to have both.

Answer (score 1):

```
  --force        force resource updates through a replacement strategy
```

https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/